# Увеличение изображений imagick

Tags: imagick, php, изображения

Как с помощью класса `imagick` для `php` увеличить изображение? Получается чёрная картинка нужных размеров.

`GD` использовать не хочу.

`Imagick module version 3.1.0RC1`

`ImageMagick 6.7.3-1`

**Добавлено**:

```
$img = new Imagick('image.jpg');
$img->resizeImage($w,$h,0,0); // $w,$h - больше чем размеры изображения
$img->writeImage('image.jpg');
```

Comment: а код какой вы используете ?

Comment: Поменяйте значение фильтра (третий параметр resizeImage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что вам возвращает функция $img->resizeImage? Делайте проверку на TRUE. К тому же, с чего вы решили, что константа фильтра равна 0? Используйте константы класса.

UPD: данный код у меня заработал без проблем (картинка лежала в директории со скриптом)

```
$file = __dir__."\image.jpg";
$img = new Imagick($file);
$result = $img->resizeImage(1516, 1864, imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED , 1); 
unlink($file);
$img->writeImage(__dir__.'\image.jpg');
```

Comment: @Zhukov Roman дело в том, что imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED -- это и есть 0. Там надо задавать другой фильтр. Какой -- х/з. Я брал из примера FILTER_LANCZOS.

Comment: Не в фильтре дело.

Comment: @Zhukov Roman а в чём? Ставлю FILTER_LANCZOS -- есть картинка, ставлю FILTER_UNDEFINED -- чёрное поле. Результат resizeImage -- 1 в обоих случаях. Что не так?

Comment: @alexlz, четвертый параметр — blur, должен равняться 1. У меня с любым фильтром получается при blur = 1. (Если читали документацию, то поймете).

Comment: Я об этом и писал.
В итоге получается, если хотим увеличивать изображение в imagick, следует устанавливать blur в 1.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, если выставить четвертый параметр в единицу, то всё работает независимо от фильтра:

```
$img->resizeImage($w,$h,0,1);
```

Если не хочется, то можно выставить какой-то фильтр, тогда четвёртый параметр можно выставить в ноль(не работает с imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED):

```
$img->resizeImage($w,$h,imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,0);
```

PS: resizeImage() всегда возвращает true, даже если чёрная картинка.
Спасибо всем.

Comment: Вы хоть читали, что делает четвертый параметр?

Comment: Нет, но теперь узнал, что это он отвечает за blur.

Comment: @jQuery осталось узнать, что значит 1 в чётвертом параметре. Потому как по описанию blurr < 1 -- резкое изображение, > 1 -- размытое...

Comment: И чтобы не трогать четкость (размытость), то он должен быть равен 1. blur > 0 должен быть. Иначе будет черная картинка.

Comment: Не уверен, но изображение вроде немного сглаживается.

Comment: @jQuery, поставьте blur = 0.1 - увидите четкость.

Comment: @Zhukov_Roman, пробовал, изображение принимает решётчатый вид и совсем портится. Минимальный параметр при увеличении, насколько я понял - 1.